# Передача канальной переменной между контекстами

Tags: asterisk

Делаю простой обзвон по контактам с помощью asterisk
Пример кода который работает, но необходимо из контекста zvonar-dialer передать ${EXTEN} (номер вызываемого) в контекст zvonar-informer на вход скрипта который написан на python.
Помогите плиз, как сделать?

Пробовал Set(), но как я понял, канальная переменная не передается никак..

```
[zvonar-dialer]
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/zadarma/+7${EXTEN:1},60) ;Звоним наружу
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup ;Вешаем трубку

[zvonar-informer]
exten => 2222,1,Answer ;Берём трубку
exten => 2222,n,Wait(1) ;Ждём 1 секунду
exten => 2222,n,BackGround(zvonar) ;Проигрываем аудиофайл
exten => 2222,n,WaitExten() ;ждем цифры от клиента

;при нажатии 1 пишем файл
exten => 1,1,System(python3 /etc/asterisk/script/zvonar/test.py ??? 1 &)
exten => 1,n,Hangup() ; Кладем трубку
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен! Сделал так

```
[zvonar-dialer]
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/zadarma/+7${EXTEN:1},40) ;Звоним наружу
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup ;Вешаем трубку

[zvonar-informer]
exten => 2222,1,Answer ;Берём трубку
exten => 2222,n,Wait(1) ;Ждём 1 секунду
exten => 2222,n,BackGround(zvonar) ;Проигрываем аудиофайл
exten => 2222,n,WaitExten() ;ждем цифры от клиента

;при нажатии 1 пишем файл
exten => 1,1,System(python3 /etc/asterisk/script/zvonar/zvonar.py ${CHANNEL:6:11} ${EXTEN} &)
exten => 1,n,Hangup() ; Кладем трубку
```

Хотя можно было сделать по другому. Например:

```
[zvonar-dialer]
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/zadarma/+7${EXTEN:1},40) ;Звоним наружу
exten => _8XXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup ;Вешаем трубку

[zvonar-informer]
exten => 2222,1,Answer ;Берём трубку
exten => 2222,n,Wait(1) ;Ждём 1 секунду
exten => 2222,n,BackGround(zvonar) ;Проигрываем аудиофайл
exten => 2222,n,WaitExten() ;ждем цифры от клиента

;при нажатии 1 пишем файл
exten => 1,1,Set(NUMBER=${CHANNEL():6:11}) 
exten => 1,1,System(python3 /etc/asterisk/script/zvonar/zvonar.py ${NUMBER} ${EXTEN} &)
exten => 1,n,Hangup() ; Кладем трубку
```